# operators that commute with idempotent operators

Tags: linear-algebra

If E is an idempotent operator on a finite dimensional vector space say V and T is another linear operator on the same space V that commutes with E i.e. TE=ET, then what can said about T?

Comment: $T^n E=ET^n$ for example. Where do you want to go?

Comment: If anything like whether it is idempotent/self-adjoint/normal or anything similar can be said about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check that $T$ commutes with $E$ if and only if you can write
$$
 T = ETE + (1-E)T(1-E),
$$
which is that same thing as saying that $T$ is block-diagonal with respect to the direct sum decomposition $V = \operatorname{im}(E) \oplus \operatorname{im}(1-E)$, i.e.,
$$
 T = \begin{pmatrix} T_1 & 0 \\ 0 & T_2 \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $T_1 : \operatorname{im}(E) \to \operatorname{im}(E)$ and $T_2 : \operatorname{im}(1-E) \to \operatorname{im}(1-E)$. This is really the most that you can say about the structure of $T$ commuting with $E$. In terms of invariant subspaces, you could equivalently say that commutes with $E$ if and only if it leaves $\operatorname{im}(E)$ invariant *and* leaves $\operatorname{im}(1-E)$ invariant.

Comment: I think that's really all you can get for $E^2 = E$...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is that $T$ would leave the subspace $E(V)$ invariant, because, for all $w \in E(V)$, $w = E(w)$ (since $E$ is idempotent) and
$$
T(w) = TE(w) = ET(w) \in E(V)
$$

Comment: what does the notation E(V) stand for?

Comment: The image of $V$. ie $\{E(v) : v\in V\}$

Comment: can we say anything about the nature of T like whether it is self adjoint/normal or any similar thing??

Comment: Not unless you know something about $E$. Take $E$ to be the identity operator - every $T$ satisfies this property!

Comment: this is obvious that T would leave the image space of E invariant,,,also it is obvious that it would leave the null space of E invariant...I want to know any particular nature of T.

Comment: Like what? Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: I think the information that E is idempotent is sufficient to know all the characteristics of E