# Show that the only matrices commuting with idempotent matrices are scalar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

The following question is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054084/show-that-the-collection-of-matrices-which-commute-with-every-idempotent-matrix) but I want to know how far away my attempt is from being correct. Let $P, A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ where $P^2=P$ and $AP=PA.$ Show that $A$ must be a scalar matrix.

My attempt: Since $P^2=P,$ if $\text{rank} P= n-k,$ we know that $P$ must be diagonalisable with eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ with multiplicities $k$ and $n-k$ respectively. Further, $P^2=P$ implies $\text{ker P} \cap \text{range} P=\{0\}$ and $\text{range} P = \text{ker}(P-I)$ so if $V$ is a real vector space of dimension $n$ then $V= \text{ker}P \bigoplus \text{range}P= \text{ker}(P-I) \bigoplus \text{ker}(P-I).$ Also, since $AP=PA, $ both $\text{ker}(P-I) $ and $\text{ker}P$ are invariant under $A$ so if $B=\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $P,$ then the matrix of $A$ with respect to $B$ must be block diagonal. It remains to show that each of these blocks must be scalar matrices, with the same scalar. In short, I have gotten as far as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/502689/360587) answer has but have been unable to make further headway. Any hints on finishing along this line of argument? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You have so far been working with one idempotent matrix. But the question you reference involves matrices which commute with every idempotent matrix. So the next thing you have to do is to deploy this fact, noting that given the matrix $A$ works for every idempotent matrix, you can choose which idempotent matrix you take (eg see the answer to the question which you linked)

Comment: Put more bluntly, your question, *as stated*, is wrong.  If $P$ is an non-scalar idempotent, then $A=P$ commutes with $P$, but $A$ is not scalar.

Comment: So basically I haven't used the hypothesis that the commutativity holds for all idempotent matrices. Instead I falsely restricted it to a single idempotent matrix.